# How to make a title span over two columns in html?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to construct 3-columned page like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make a title to span over only two columns?
Using exclusions gives no result=( I'm stuck!

I need to do 3 columns with floating text:

```
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-rule: 2px solid #B8B8B8;
```

so using table is not a solution

Comment: Could you provide us some of your HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 offers `column-count` specifically for this purpose but unfortunately it's not supported in old browsers.

```
.newspaper
{
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gt4qP/)

Comment: That's the one i use, but tell me how to add a title over only 2 columns?

Comment: You will have to restrict the width of header I guess

Comment: Of course i can, but the last column will stand at the same height. I mean that the last column should be higher than the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DIV with style `float:left` to place 2 columns next to each other. And the DIV with title could go above them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6cttL/

Comment: I need to do 3 columns with floating text so using table is not a solution for me.

Comment: Um.. This answer *does not* suggest using table.

Comment: That's right, but furthermore it doesn't support floating text=(

Answer (score 1):

I needed the solution to this exact problem and found this at kmsm.ca:

Spanning columns

If we want an element, say a headline, to span across multiple columns we can make use of the new column-span property.

column-span has two possible values: all, and regular numbers (e.g. 1,2,3). Defining column-span as all means that the given element will span across the whole multi-column block, while assigning it a regular number will limit its span to that number of columns:

```
h2 {
    -webkit-column-span:all;
    -moz-column-span:all;
    column-span:all;
}
```

hope that helps
update - this worked in Chrome but not Firefox

Comment: [This site](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#spanning-columns) says that column-span has two possible values: all and none. So it could not be a regular number. Have you try this by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a table with colspan?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" id="title">

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="firstcolumn">

        </td>
        <td id="secondcolumn">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using a table for layout purposes with non-tabular data is generally frowned upon. It's semantically incorrect, confusing to people on screen readers, and harder to maintain.

Comment: "Generally frowned upon" is possibly the politest way I've ever heard that described

Comment: I think people get overly dogmatic about it. The fact is, it's not forbidden by the spec (it even gives guidance on *how* to use tables for layout), and sometimes it's simply the most elegant solution. But in this case there are more appropriate elements that will solve the problem.

Comment: I've add a comment. I need a flow text, so table is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your document structure is beneath that image, but a common technique is to place a 'wrapper' div around blocks of content to simplify their layout.

So, you'd place the far right content in a div, then everything on the left in a div. Within the left div, you'd have your heading, then below it, a div that contained the two columns.

```
<div id="rightMain">...</div> <!--Float right-->
<div id="leftMain">
    <h2>Article Title</h2>
    <div id="article">
        <div id="leftArticleCol">...</div>
        <div id="rightArticleCol">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```